# How to get the Count of rows where either of two columns dates should be greater than a given date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has two columns **created_at** and **updated_at**. These two columns store the date. **Created_at** stores the time when the row was created and **updated_at** stores the time when there was any updation in the row.

[image]

Now, I need to find out the number of rows which were either created at or updated at after a given ZonedTimeData.

Comment: please provide the table schema and example data as formatted text not as an image

Comment: `updated_at` cannot be lower than `created_at` (or you have some serious problems). So one column testing is enough. For "either created at or updated at after a given ZonedTimeData" this is `updated_at`. And it is strange that `updated_at` may be NULL - do you assign it manually and do not use autoutilizing? Fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **OR** statement to take the row whose created_at or updated_at is greater than the desired date.

```
Select count(*) from table
where (created_at >= '<yourDate>' OR updated_at >= '<yourDate>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give your `DateTime` value in the below `<yourDate>`. You can use below `created_at` or replace it with `updated_at`

```
select count(*)
from table
where created_at >= '<yourDate>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `where` clause:

```
select count(*)
from t
where created_at >= ? or updated_at >= ?;
```

Where `?` is a parameter placeholder for the date/time value you care about.

Or, you might want where the *last* change was after a certain date:

```
select count(*)
from t
where coalesce(updated_at, created_at) >= ?;
```